# If exception handling is not allowed, How object construction of a class can be stopped if parameter passed is found wrong?

Tags: c++11

```
class Date
{
    Date(int day, int month, int year) {     }
}
int main()
{
    Date d = Date(100, 2, 1990);
}
```

Here value(100) passed to day is not right, My question is how 'day' parameter can be checked in constructor to prevent creation of object.
Please note exception handling is not allowed

Comment: Why isn't exception handling allowed? Seems like the best way to do something like this...

Comment: @thomson_matt: Does it matter why exceptions aren't allowed? There are platforms where they aren't; the reasoning is irrelevant to answering his question. Yeah, it sucks, but he's asking how to deal with the poor environment.

Answer (score 3):

One of the arguments often leveled against modern C++ programming techniques like RAII is that they can't be used in the absence of exceptions, since exceptions are the only way to signal a constructor's failure. And that's absolutely true.

The only way to deal with an environment where exceptions are not allowed is to take initialization out of the constructor. Do it in a member function or something.

Just remember: environments without exceptions are not true C++. You have to treat them more like C-with-classes.

Answer (score 2):

Once I talked to software engeeners who had been dveloping on eCos a C++ project and did not have C++ exceptions supported by the compiler. As a result they did not use throwing exceptions in constructors.

They approach was to use simple constructors like this

```
Date::Date()
 :
 initialized_ (false)
{}
```

and then `init` function was always used:

```
bool Date::init(int day, int month, int year)
{
    // return false if there is an error while initializing the object
    // return true if there is no error
    initialized_ = true;

}
```

They always checked the result of `init()` functions.

Comment: It seems ok, But is it possible to assign a default value to the class member. like initialized_ (false)